# How can I JSON stringify and then parse an object with functions? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, object, parsing, stringify

I have an object with both attributes and functions, and I want to be able to stringify them into JSON, then parse them back out again for a save-load system. Keep in mind, the data has circular components.

I tried using flatted, but then I ran into the problem where I did not know how to revive the object properly. I'm still new to JSON, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: JSON doesn't store functions, just data. You'd have to store the functions as strings (`fn.toString()`).

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus Oh, I see. How should I go about converting the functions inside of objects into strings and vice versa?

Comment: I really don't think that you _should_ do that. Can you explain a bit more what it is that you are trying to achieve and why? There has to be another way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description):

> undefined, **Function**, and Symbol values are not valid JSON values. If any such values are encountered during conversion, they are either omitted (when found in an object) or changed to null (when found in an array).

So what you want is just not possible.

Even if you would construct a string yourself that resembles a 'stringified function', then `JSON.parse()` will not be able to handle it like you would want it to do.

Comment: Oh no! Is there any way I can save the object while keeping the functions intact? How do websites save objects with functions attached?

Comment: "How do websites save objects with functions attached": well, they don't. In fact I know of no systems that do so. Code is code, data is data, and although objects can "contain" both, saving/loading only applies to the data parts.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know what I have to do now. Instead of saving the object itself just save the important data points. It's more work, but at least it's plausible.